# Conditional Probability of balls in cells

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose that we have nr balls where $n \geq 2,r \geq 2$. The balls are numbered $1, 2, \ldots, nr$. The balls are placed into n cells with no restriction on the number of balls allowed per cell. Assume each ball is placed into a cell independently of other balls. Given that each of the n cells has exactly r balls. Find the conditional probability that the balls numbered $1,2, \ldots, n$ are in different cells.
Let D denote the event that the balls numbered $1,2, \ldots, n$ are in different cells and let $E$ denote the event that each cell has exactly $r$ balls.
So we are looking for: $P(D|E)= \frac{P(D \cap E)}{P(E)}$
I have found that $P(E)=\frac{(nr)!}{(r!)^nn^{nr}}$
I am having trouble finding $P(D \cap E)$, does anybody have any ideas on who to find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combinatorics of this problem look particularly simple, so let's see how much we can progress by tackling it head-on:

1. There are $\binom{nr}{r,r,\ldots,r} = \frac{(nr)!}{(r!)^n}$ equally likely ways to partition $nr$ objects into groups of size $r,r,\ldots,r.$
2. There are $n! = \binom{n}{1,1,\ldots,1}$ ways to partition the first $n$ objects, one per group.
3. There are $\binom{n(r-1)}{r-1,r-1,\ldots,r-1} = \frac{(n(r-1))!}{((r-1)!)^n}$ ways to partition the remaining $n(r-1)$ objects into groups of size $r-1$ *independently of the partitioning of the first $n.$*

Therefore the chance must be the product of the last two divided by the first: that will answer your question.